# JqWidget tabs - dynamically add tab with ajax content

Tags: jqwidget

I want create a dynamic on click append data to tab but I get in the tab undefined. Could you tell me whats wrong? Not quite sure what is the case,

My js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Create jqxTabs.
            $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs({ width: 580, height: 200,showCloseButtons: true });
            var length = $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('length') + 1;
            var loadPage = function (url) {
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                  data;
                    // console.log( $('#content' + length ).text(data));
                    // console.log(data);
                });
            }
            $('div.s span').click(function() {
                var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('addFirst', 'Sample title',loadPage(getvalue).text());
                $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('ensureVisible', -1);


});


            // $('#jqxTabs').on('selected', function (event) {
                // var pageIndex = event.args.item + 1;
                // loadPage('pages/ajax' + pageIndex + '.htm', pageIndex);
            // });
        });
    </script>
```

My html

```
<div class="s">
<span rel="gen.php">Load</span>
</div>
 <div id='jqxWidget'>
        <div id='jqxTabs'>
            <ul>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first check the right syntax for tab control:

HTML:

```
....
<div id='jqxTabs'>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Create jqxTabs.
$('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs({ width: 580, height: 200, showCloseButtons: true });
$('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs("removeFirst"); //here removes the empty tab

//here the function must return the content, and the ajax must be async false for this purpose
var loadPage = function (url) {
    var result = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        } 
    });
    return result;
}

$('div.s span').click(function() {
    var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('addFirst', 'Sample title', loadPage(getvalue));
    $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('ensureVisible', -1);
});
```

For better understanding check: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesrv/h4573ykv/1/

**EDIT:** For the new condition, use a custom attribute so checking would be easier:

```
$('div.s span').click(function() {
    var getvalue = $(this).attr('rel');
    var opened = $(this).attr('opened');

    if (!opened) {
        $(this).attr('opened', true);
        $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('addFirst', 'Sample title', loadPage(getvalue));
        $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs('ensureVisible', -1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Invalid Selector - #jqxTabs! Please, check whether the used ID or CSS Class name is correct. Using your code

Comment: Please add a fiddle for better understanding, because I've tried it and have no problem

Comment: Working as expected 1 more thing. Can we anyhow make a user unable to open same tab twice from the link? So we open out gen.php - we set the title to Simple title Gen for example. And now we check if its already opened if not add else we generate a alert

Comment: For that purpose, you can add a custom attribute in the span and each onclick check if its set

Comment: Oh last thing as you know when we open the tab its ok but when we close it and want to open it again the attribute stays opened, we need to add a handle for onclose remove attribute.